# tmhOAuth failed to validate oauth signature and token

Tags: php, twitter-oauth, http-status-code-401

I'm trying to use The Matt Harris's oAuth php library to get user access tokens from Twitter users on my app, but I keep getting the error "Failed to validate oauth signature and token".

Specifically, I'm trying to use a slightly modified version of his OAuth flow tutorial to get their tokens and store them in my database rather than the session. https://github.com/themattharris/tmhOAuth/blob/master/examples/oauth_flow.php 
The error always occurs in the request token function here.

```
function request_token($tmhOAuth) {
    $code = $tmhOAuth->request(
       'POST',
       $tmhOAuth->url('oauth/request_token', ''),
       array(
           'oauth_callback' => tmhUtilities::php_self()
       )
    );

    if ($code == 200) {
        $_SESSION['oauth'] = $tmhOAuth->extract_params($tmhOAuth->response['response']);
       authorize($tmhOAuth);
    } else {
       outputError($tmhOAuth);
    }
}
```

I've already checked the server time, and I know it's within 5 seconds of GMT. One of the Twitter developers said the time should be within about 5 minutes of their servers, so I should be fine. https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/1043

I've also checked that the `cacert.pem` file is in the same place as the rest of the files, right where CURL expects it to be, and I have the 'use_ssl' and 'curl_ssl_verifypeer' options turned off, since my site does not currently have an SSL certificate set up.

Here is the returned response object:

```
["response"]=> array(6) { 
        ["headers"]=> array(16) { 
            ["date"]=> string(29) "Sat, 25 Aug 2012 16:38:24 GMT" 
            ["status"]=> string(16) "401 Unauthorized" 
            ["x_frame_options"]=> string(10) "SAMEORIGIN" 
            ["x_mid"]=> string(40) "4147a367997b7a5221cbcd8446652b1ebc00230d" 
            ["last_modified"]=> string(29) "Sat, 25 Aug 2012 16:38:24 GMT" 
            ["content_type"]=> string(24) "text/html; charset=utf-8" 
            ["expires"]=> string(29) "Tue, 31 Mar 1981 05:00:00 GMT" 
            ["cache_control"]=> string(62) "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate, pre-check=0, post-check=0" 
            ["x_runtime"]=> string(7) "0.01766" 
            ["pragma"]=> string(8) "no-cache" 
            ["x_transaction"]=> string(16) "b8ffe07df233ba05" 
            ["set_cookie"]=> string(265) "_twitter_sess=ginormous session id; domain=.twitter.com; path=/; HttpOnly" 
            ["vary"]=> string(15) "Accept-Encoding" 
            ["content_encoding"]=> string(4) "gzip" 
            ["content_length"]=> string(2) "62" 
            ["server"]=> string(3) "tfe"
        } 
        ["code"]=> int(401) 
        ["response"]=> string(44) "Failed to validate oauth signature and token" 
        ["info"]=> array(23) { 
            ["url"]=> string(42) "http://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token" 
            ["content_type"]=> string(24) "text/html; charset=utf-8" 
            ["http_code"]=> int(401) ["header_size"]=> int(1030) 
            ["request_size"]=> int(498) ["filetime"]=> int(-1) 
            ["ssl_verify_result"]=> int(0) 
            ["redirect_count"]=> int(0) 
            ["total_time"]=> float(0.265656) 
            ["namelookup_time"]=> float(0.062211) 
            ["connect_time"]=> float(0.139025) 
            ["pretransfer_time"]=> float(0.139028) 
            ["size_upload"]=> float(0) 
            ["size_download"]=> float(62) 
            ["speed_download"]=> float(233) 
            ["speed_upload"]=> float(0) 
            ["download_content_length"]=> float(62) 
            ["upload_content_length"]=> float(-1) 
            ["starttransfer_time"]=> float(0.265504) 
            ["redirect_time"]=> float(0) 
            ["certinfo"]=> array(0) { } 
            ["redirect_url"]=> string(0) "" 
            ["request_header"]=> string(498) "POST /oauth/request_token HTTP/1.1 User-Agent: tmhOAuth 0.621-SSL - //github.com/themattharris/tmhOAuth Host: api.twitter.com Accept: */* Accept-Encoding: deflate, gzip Authorization: OAuth oauth_callback="http%3A%2F%2Fcompleteset.us%2Fsettings%2Ftwitterlink", oauth_consumer_key="consumer_key", oauth_nonce="nonce", oauth_signature="sig", oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1", oauth_timestamp="1345912704", oauth_version="1.0" " 
        } 
        ["error"]=> string(0) "" 
        ["errno"]=> int(0) 
    }
```

I have noticed that before I set 'use_ssl' to false the headers array in the response wasn't there. I'm not sure what that means or if it helps, but I figured I might as well throw it out there.

I also have the entire rest of the tmhOAuth object dumped if you need any of the other sections.

Comment: i spent too many time to try to make it work too and never had answer from his author. :( thus I had have to switch to the OAuth module of ZendFramework. I hope you will find someone who will be able to help you

Comment: I haven't had to look back at the zend documentation in so long I forgot that it even had oAuth. I'll have to check it out. Thanks for reminding me.

Comment: did you have a look at this ? http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.oauth.introduction.html

Comment: For some reason, zend doesn't provide any examples of getting the token strings, just the token objects. I was just making things harder on myself by trying to use the `toQueryString()` function of the Token_Access class rather than just going to it's parent and using the accessors.